# How to bind event on view element in BackboneJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to bind a click event on a div (which is inside a backbone view)

Here is the code which I create the view and set event for it

```
dialogModel = new Dialog.SimpleWindowModel({
                title: 'export:export.dialog.title',
                data: {
                    message: 'export:export.dialog.message',
                    downloadPDF: 'export:export.dialog.downloadPDF',
                    shareByQRCode: 'export:export.dialog.shareByQRCode',
                    sendEmail: 'export:export.dialog.sendEmail',
                },
                bodyTemplate: exportTpl,
            });

dialogView = new Dialog.WindowView({ model: dialogModel });

dialogView.on('click .download-pdf', function () {console.log("ff");});
dialogView.on('click .share-qr-code', ExportAction.shareByQRCode);
dialogView.on('click .send-email', ExportAction.sendEmail);
```

This is the view template:

```
<div class="export-button-container">
  <div class="btn export-button download-pdf">
      <img src="https://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/PDF.jpg"/>
      <p class='dialog-message' data-i18n>{{downloadPDF}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn export-button share-qr-code">
      <img src="https://www.qrstuff.com/images/sample.png"/>
      <p class='dialog-message' data-i18n>{{shareByQRCode}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn export-button send-email">
      <img src="https://d1hoh05jeo8jse.cloudfront.net/media/google/gmail-icon.jpg"/>
      <p class='dialog-message' data-i18n>{{sendEmail}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected that when I click the div with class="download-pdf", console.log("ff"); will be executed, but it wasn't.

How to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Not sure why this question deserves a downvote, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) method is only intended for use with [**internal Backbone events**](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) such as `add` or `remove`, not ***DOM*** events such as `click`. For DOM events you have to use View's [`events`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events) hash/method which can be specified in a custom view class or passed as an option to a View constructor.

For your code, where view class definition is obscured, you may use the 2nd option (passing to constructor):

```
dialogView = new Dialog.WindowView({
    model: dialogModel,
    events: {
        'click .download-pdf': function () {console.log("ff");},
        'click .share-qr-code': ExportAction.shareByQRCode,
        'click .send-email': ExportAction.sendEmail
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example code? The link about View's events is very confused, it's still internal Backbone events

Comment: Ah, do you mean that we have to add all events inside "events" hash of the model?

Comment: _The link about View's events is very confused.._ Imho that docs is quite comprehensible and even has a code example. What does exactly confuse you there?

Comment: I thought that we need to add those events to the place where we define initialize, render methods. Now I know that we can pass them as parameters :D Thank you very much. 

One more thing, if my Dialog.WindowView view has 2 events already, does this stack up so that dialogView has 5 events in total? Or just 3 events and get rid of 2 existing events?

Comment: _if my Dialog.WindowView view has 2 events already, does this stack up so that dialogView has 5 events in total?_ AFAIK options passed to a constructor **aren't merged** with respective class properties, but **replace** them instead. So `events` hash passed to a constructor will override/replace its counterpart defined in class.

Comment: @HoangTrinh If you ever want to create a base class where sub-class events are merged with the base class defaults, check out [how to create a good base class for Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982556/1218980).