# Passed parameter to initialize() view is undefined in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm working on a Backbone.js app which utilizes a 'master view' which all views and subviews extend from.

**Master view**

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
   return Backbone.View.extend({
      events: {

      },

      showSuccess: function (msg) {
         alert(msg);
      }
   });
});
```

I then have a **Main View** which generates the page, this can call on sub views for smaller parts:

```
define(['backbone','masterView', 'mySubView'], function (Backbone, mView, mySubView) {
   var mainView = mView.extend({
      events: function () {
         return _.extend({}, coreView.prototype.events, {

         });
      },

      render: function () {
         var sub = new mySubView({'foo': 'bar'});
      }
   });
   return new mainView();
});
```

Finally, my **subview**, which when it's initialised, it says that `options` is undefined.

```
define(['backbone','masterView', 'mySubView'], function (Backbone, mView, mySubView) {
   var subView = mView.extend({
      events: function () {
         return _.extend({}, coreView.prototype.events, {

         });
      },

      initialize: function (options) {
         console.log(options);
      }
   });
   return new subView();
});
```

In this setup, why is `options` undefined when I passed them in my `MainView`? If the subview doesn't extend `masterView`, but `Backbone.view` instead, it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last line in the subview file:

```
return new subView();
```

You're returning a new instance instead of returning the constructor in the **subview** module. It should be:

```
return subView;
```

Note that [as a convention, JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/921133/1218980) code should use **PascalCase** for types (constructor, classes, etc.), and instances (variables, properties, etc.) should use **camelCase**.

Also, I'm sharing tricks on [how to design a good base class with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982556/1218980). You could shift the responsibility of merging the events to the base class instead of each child class.

Comment: thanks for the additional formatting tips and further reading!